# Can INSERT when UPDATING but not when INSERTING

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
            create or replace trigger UPDATE_HISTORY
            BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MAIN_TABLE
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN

            IF UPDATING THEN

            INSERT INTO HISTORY(
                ID,
                STATUS_ID
            )
            VALUES 
            (
                :OLD.ID,
                :OLD.STATUS_ID
            );

            ELSE

            :NEW.id := id_seq.nextval; 

            INSERT INTO HISTORY(
                ID,
                STATUS_ID
            )
            VALUES 
            (
                :NEW.ID,
                :NEW.STATUS_ID
            );

            END IF;

            END;
```

I am currently experiencing a problem where I am able to insert data when creating a new record in MAIN_TABLE but when I come to update a record within this table it throws back and error. I am using a sequence to create a new id for the History table.

The error I'm receiving is "violated - parent key not found" / "  line 21 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger".

Comment: Is there any constraints (Foreign Key, Primary Key) on the main table or history table? The error seems related to that.

Comment: Do you have any foreign keys on either the MAIN_TABLE or HISTORY table?

Comment: You can run the following query to find out: `SELECT *
  FROM user_cons_columns
 WHERE table_name = '<your table name>';`

Comment: I do, ID is the PK of MAIN_TABLE and the FK of HISTORY

Comment: That tells the whole story

Comment: The question title and the text are contradictory.  The title implies that the error occurs on INSERT statements but not on UPDATE statements, while your text says the opposite.  I believe that with this trigger you will get errors on all INSERT statements and may get errors on UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two situations here which I think will cause an error.

The one that I think you are hitting is on inserting a new row.  You are trying to insert into the history table *before* the insert into the main table actually occurs.  Therefore, the foreign key constraint is violated because there is no parent record for the child to reference.  To avoid this, you could set the constraint to be deferred, so it is not checked until you commit; or use an AFTER trigger to do the insert into the history table.

The other problem would be if an update changed the ID of the row in the main table.  The trigger would insert a history record; then the update itself would fail because a child record existed with the old ID value.  This is probably the desired behavior, as you generally don't want people modifying PK values anyway.

Comment: I would agree on the second problem. But the first, does not contradict what the OP mentioned?  `I am able to insert data when creating a new record in MAIN_TABLE but when I come to update a record within this table it throws back and error`.

Comment: Cheers mate, that really helped.

Comment: I agree it is a contradiction - but the title of the question contradicts the text so I am not sure what to believe except the code.

Answer (score 0):

So according to your comment `ID is the PK of MAIN_TABLE and the FK of HISTORY`:
And according to the referrential integrity rule:

> A foreign key is a way to enforce referential integrity within your Oracle database. A foreign key means that values in one table must also appear in another table.
>
> The referenced table is called the parent table while the table with the foreign key is called the child table. The foreign key in the child table will generally reference a primary key in the parent table.

**On INSERT:** Your trigger will insert the new ID (that is inserted into the MAIN_TABLE),into History table. So here, the FK (which is ID in HISTORY) has PK in MAIN_TABLE - works fine.

**On UPDATE:** , however, the ID in your MAIN_TABLE has already been replaced with new ID. But you are trying to insert the old one into History table (which is already replaced in the MAIN_TABLE). So this FK does not appear in MAIN_TABLE anymore. This violates your referential integrity rule you have it in place.

**EXAMPLE**
You have a row with ID=3 in MAIN_TABLE, and you update it to ID=5. On update, your trigger is trying to insert ID=3 into History (:old.ID). But 3 does not exist anymore in MAIN_TABLE

**SOLUTION**
It all depends on the logic you want to implement, and what are you trying to achieve. If you want to store the :old.ID, you might need to remove FK constraint on this particular column. or you probably want to store :old.ID in anther column and use :new.ID as FK

Read about FK [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php)

Comment: The example shown is a BEFORE trigger; so the changes to the main table would happen after the trigger executes.  Your answer is more correct for an AFTER trigger, I think.

Comment: @DaveCosta You are right, I was misled by `I am able to insert data when creating a new record in MAIN_TABLE but when I come to update a record within this table it throws back and error`